# Splitting a string based on commas between words with special conditions - Python

Tags: python, regex

My problem is this, there is a string

```
[word in IN ('hello', 'world'), key1=1100, key2=1200]
```

I need a list that would contain

```
[word in IN ('hello', 'world'),
 key1=1100,
 key2=1200
]
```

Obviously splitting by comma doesn't work, so went with regular expression grouping.

```
pattern= re.compile(r"(.*), [a-zA-Z]?", re.DOTALL)
string = "[word in IN ('hello', 'world'), key1=1100, key2=1200]"
for item in re.findall(pattern, string):
    print item
```

What I am trying to do is to match only the commas after which space and an alphabet would occur, but for me, it giving wrong results.

```
[word in IN ('hello', 'world'), key1=1100
```

Still, it's greedy matching. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with a *positive lookahead*:

```
In [3]: re.split(r", (?=[a-zA-Z])", s)
Out[3]: ["[word in IN ('hello', 'world')", 'key1=1100', 'key2=1200]']
```